Can not start API on Azure using Node.js
I am trying to run simple API on AZURE but it could not start.
Looks like there are some problems with docker containers but I did not use docker on this project at all.
2024-06-11T12:38:06.250Z ERROR - Container smapi_0_41997ae8 for site smapi did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.9409353 sec
2024-06-11T12:38:06.269Z ERROR - Container smapi_0_41997ae8 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

Below is a full output
2024-06-11T12:34:13.639389363Z    _____                               
2024-06-11T12:34:13.639439868Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____  
2024-06-11T12:34:13.639445369Z  /  /_\  \\___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \ 
2024-06-11T12:34:13.639449669Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/ 
2024-06-11T12:34:13.639453669Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2024-06-11T12:34:13.639457970Z         \/      \/                  \/ 
2024-06-11T12:34:13.639462170Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2024-06-11T12:34:13.639466270Z 
2024-06-11T12:34:13.639469971Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2024-06-11T12:34:13.639473871Z NodeJS quickstart: https://aka.ms/node-qs
2024-06-11T12:34:13.639477772Z NodeJS Version : v18.19.1
2024-06-11T12:34:13.639481672Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2024-06-11T12:34:13.639485672Z 
2024-06-11T12:34:14.780987341Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2024-06-11T12:34:15.043069764Z Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.
2024-06-11T12:34:15.351047911Z Found build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'. Deserializing it...
2024-06-11T12:34:15.351084015Z Build Operation ID: 1f0c0dc2c767d17b
2024-06-11T12:34:15.966713179Z Environment Variables for Application Insight's IPA Codeless Configuration exists..
2024-06-11T12:34:16.075344278Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194539449Z Running #!/bin/sh
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194579453Z 
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194586654Z # Enter the source directory to make sure the script runs where the user expects
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194591954Z cd "/home/site/wwwroot"
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194597054Z 
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194601855Z export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194606655Z if [ -z "$PORT" ]; then
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194611456Z      export PORT=8080
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194616356Z fi
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194620757Z 
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194625257Z echo Found tar.gz based node_modules.
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194629957Z extractionCommand="tar -xzf node_modules.tar.gz -C /node_modules"
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194634658Z echo "Removing existing modules directory from root..."
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194639358Z rm -fr /node_modules
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194643759Z mkdir -p /node_modules
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194788272Z echo Extracting modules...
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194795273Z $extractionCommand
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194800173Z export NODE_PATH="/node_modules":$NODE_PATH
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194805274Z export PATH=/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194809874Z if [ -d node_modules ]; then
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194827576Z     mv -f node_modules _del_node_modules || true
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194832476Z fi
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194836777Z 
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194840977Z if [ -d /node_modules ]; then
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194845377Z     ln -sfn /node_modules ./node_modules 
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194849978Z fi
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194861579Z 
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194865879Z echo "Done."
2024-06-11T12:34:16.194870480Z npm start
2024-06-11T12:34:16.205774283Z Found tar.gz based node_modules.
2024-06-11T12:34:16.205797885Z Removing existing modules directory from root...
2024-06-11T12:34:16.275478599Z Extracting modules...
2024-06-11T12:34:31.515363979Z Done.
2024-06-11T12:34:36.050058764Z npm info using npm@10.5.0
2024-06-11T12:34:36.059130100Z npm info using node@v18.19.1
2024-06-11T12:34:39.345107039Z 
2024-06-11T12:34:39.345148043Z > typeorm-sample@0.0.1 start
2024-06-11T12:34:39.345154944Z > ts-node src/index.ts
2024-06-11T12:34:39.345159744Z 
2024-06-11T12:34:40.042847337Z npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm 1335ms
2024-06-11T12:34:40.388046497Z npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm 2310ms
2024-06-11T12:35:17.140667787Z Express server has started on port 3000. Open http://localhost:3000/permissions to see results

2024-06-11T12:38:06.250Z ERROR - Container smapi_0_41997ae8 for site smapi did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.9409353 sec
2024-06-11T12:38:06.269Z ERROR - Container smapi_0_41997ae8 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2024-06-11T12:38:06.320Z INFO  - Stopping site smapi because it failed during startup.

I tried to change ports of  app.listen function but of course it did not work.
node@v18.19.1
npm@10.5.0

Node.js application is listening on port 3000, but Azure expects it to listen on port 8080.

Azure uses port 8080 for HTTP. As you can see the below code it runs successfully with the port number 8080.
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080; 

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, Azure!'); 
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

Output:

